# Obtain arguments from a string seperated by a space and convert an argument in an array format to an array

Tags: javascript, regex, command-line-arguments

I have arguments that will be passed by the user for a command. Each argument for a command will be seperated with a space, which will represent a new argument. Example: `"arg1 arg2 arg3"` converts to `["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]` where the output is a JS array. This can be done with a simple `.split(" ").`

However, my problem begin when trying to format an array as a command argument. My goal is to allow the user to enter an agument in the format of an array (e.g. Starts with `[` may contain multiple elements seperated by a `,` and ends with a `]`) so for example: `"arg1 [elem1, elem2] arg3"` converts to `["arg1", ["elem1", "elem2"], "arg3"]` where the inner and outer array is a JS array.

I have tried using JSON.Parse() however, each element would require the user to have `"` at the start of each element which is too complex for the user and non essential to be inputting. Also, the elements may not always intend to be a `string` and may be Boolean, Number or a custom type.

As of currently, this has been my best solution but misses some requirements and also is non functional when an array has a space inside.

```
s.split(/[\[\]]|\s+/).filter(arg => arg.length > 1);
```

I have come up with some other solutions but all are missing one thing or another in the required specification set above. A solution that can handle nested arrays would be nice however it is non-essential and could make the solution alot more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume no funny characters as the input. Also nesting not allowed.

```js
var str = "arg1 [ elem1  , elem2,elem3  ]  arg3";
console.log(str)

// removing white spaces from the [ array ]
str = str.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ',');
str = str.replace(/\[\s*/g, '[');
str = str.replace(/\s*\]/g, ']');

// now split on words
var arr = str.split(/\s+/);
arr = arr.map(function(elem) {

  // if begins with [ it is assumed to be an array to be splitted
  return elem.charAt(0) == '[' ? elem.slice(1, -1).split(",") : elem;
})

console.log(arr)
```